# How to work with raml?

Tags: mule, raml

I'm working with raml first time my raml file looks like below.

```
#%RAML 0.8
title: Contact
version: 1
baseUri: http://abc/api/{version}
traits:
  - client-id-required:
      queryParameters:
        client_id:
          type: string
        client_secret:
          type: string
/contact:
  post:
    is: [client-id-required]
    description: Create a new contact record
    body:
      application/json:
        example: !include contactCreateReq_sample.json
        schema: !include contactCreateReq.json
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            example: !include contactCreateRes_sample.json
            schema: !include contactCreateRes.json
  put:
    is: [client-id-required]
    description: update a customer record
    body:
      application/json:
        example: !include contactUpdateReq_sample.json
        schema: !include contactUpdateReq.json
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            example: !include contactUpdateRes_sample.json
            schema: !include contactUpdateRes.json
  delete:
    is: [client-id-required]
    description: update a customer record
    body:
      application/json:
        example: !include contactUpdateReq_sample.json
        schema: !include contactUpdateReq.json
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            example: !include contactUpdateRes_sample.json
            schema: !include contactUpdateRes.json    
  /{functionId}:
    post:
      is: [client-id-required]
      description: Create a new contact function record
      responses:
        200:
          body:
            application/json:
              example: !include contactCreateReq_sample.json
              schema: !include contactCreateReq.json
    put:
      is: [client-id-required]
      description: Update an existing contact function record
      responses:
        200:
          body:
            application/json:
              example: !include contactUpdateRes_sample.json
              schema: !include contactUpdateRes.json
```

getting below error message while running my interface,  I have couple of raml files getting same kind error in all raml file cases. It is working interface in production i'm trying to run in my local machine and got the mentioned error. please let me know anything is missing in my code ?

```
ERROR 2017-10-12 13:02:26,292 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
org.mule.module.apikit.exception.ApikitRuntimeException: Invalid API descriptor -- errors found: 1

RAML resource not found --  file: contact.raml

    at org.mule.module.apikit.parser.ParserWrapperV1.validate(ParserWrapperV1.java:68) ~[mule-module-apikit-3.8.5-HF1.jar:?]
    at org.mule.module.apikit.ParserService.validateRaml(ParserService.java:86) ~[mule-module-apikit-3.8.5-HF1.jar:?]
    at org.mule.module.apikit.AbstractConfiguration.initialise(AbstractConfiguration.java:112) ~[mule-module-apikit-3.8.5-HF1.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:237) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.MuleContextInitialisePhase.applyLifecycle(MuleContextInitialisePhase.java:71) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:99) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:71) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:155) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:126) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistry.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:116) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:177) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:100) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:102) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:54) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:203) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:63) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:136) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:58) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:317) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:172) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:261) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:76) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:279) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:151) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:134) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:172) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:33) ~[tooling-support-3.8.5.jar:?]
INFO  2017-10-12 13:02:26,292 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App 'sfdc-sap-api-interface-v4.7-prod' never started, nothing to dispose of
ERROR 2017-10-12 13:02:26,307 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Failed to deploy artifact                                +
+ 'sfdc-sap-api-interface-v4.7-prod', see below            +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: ApikitRuntimeException: Invalid API descriptor -- errors found: 1

RAML resource not found --  file: contact.raml

    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:212) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:63) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:136) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such error comes, if raml file is not present in class path while the application in being build.

**A**. If you are building ***using Anypoint Studio***.

1.Go To **Java Build Path** in your project properties.

2.Click on "**Source**" tab

3.Click on **Add Folder** button.

4.Check the folder where “contact.raml” is present. Generally raml filet is kept in the “ api” folder. Hence if it so, check “api” folder and click “**OK**”.

5.Click "**Apply**"

Add the folder where “contact.raml” is present. Generally raml filet is kept in the “ api” folder. Hence if it so, check “api” folder and click “OK”.After that clean and rebuild project.

**B**.If you are ***using maven to build the project***.

Make sure you have the "mule-module-apikit" dependency in pom file, if not add it and also specify the resource directory as below in the plugin and give it a try.Consider below example from my pom.xml

```
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
         <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.7</version>
         <executions>
             <execution>
                 <id>add-resource</id>
                 <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                 <goals>
                     <goal>add-resource</goal>
                 </goals>
                 <configuration>
                     <resources>
                         <resource>
                             <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                         </resource>
                         <resource>
                             <directory>mappings/</directory>
                         </resource>
                         <resource>
                             <directory>src/main/api</directory>
                         </resource>
                     </resources>
                 </configuration>
             </execution>
         </executions>
     </plugin>
```